# Problem with Mailkit MoveTo method either hanging or complaining about threads

Tags: c#, mailkit

I have what I believe to be simple code to open an inbox, loop through the messages and move them to trash.  For some reason, the MoveTo is hanging for exactly 2 minutes and then failing with a host name not found.  If I open a mail client, I can see that it instantly does the move successfully.  If I change the call to MoveToAsync, it also does the move, but exceptions that the iMapClient is busy on another thread.

```
            ImapClient client = new ImapClient();
            try
            {

                using (client)
                {
                    client.Connect(EXT_IMAP_SERVER, EXT_IMAP_PORT, SecureSocketOptions.None);

                    client.Authenticate(EXT_USERNAME, EXT_PASSWORD);

                    IMailFolder inbox = client.Inbox;
                    inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
                    IMailFolder deletedItems = client.GetFolder("Deleted Items");
                    int totalMessages = inbox.Count;

                    for (int i = 0; i < totalMessages; i++)
                    {
                        // get message
                        var message = inbox.GetMessage(i);
                        AddOutputMsg("Received Msg from:" + message.From);
                        //  process
                        //var theAttachments = message.Attachments;
                        //  Move to deleted items
                        inbox.MoveToAsync(i, deletedItems);
                 
                        Application.DoEvents();                        
                    }
                    client.Disconnect(true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {                
                AddOutputMsg(e.ToString());
            }
```

This is all the code in the project that uses mailkit, no other code is accessing the ImapClient.

I have tried using the lock command on the imapclient, inbox and folder and all with the same results.

Comment: `await` async methods and **never** use `DoEvents()`.